# Sklearn LDA-analysis won't generate 2 dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot a 3-feature dataset with a binary classification on a matplotlib plot. This worked with an example dataset provided in a guide (http://www.apnorton.com/blog/2016/12/19/Visualizing-Multidimensional-Data-in-Python/) but when I try to instead insert my own dataset, the LinearDiscriminantAnalysis will only output a one-dimensional series, no matter what number I put in "n_components". Why would this not work with my own code?

```
Data = pd.read_csv("DataFrame.csv", sep=";")
x = Data.iloc[:, [3, 5, 7]]
y = Data.iloc[:, 8]

lda = LDA(n_components=2)
lda_transformed = pd.DataFrame(lda.fit_transform(x, y))

plt.scatter(lda_transformed[y==0][0], lda_transformed[y==0][1], label='Loss', c='red')
plt.scatter(lda_transformed[y==1][0], lda_transformed[y==1][1], label='Win', c='blue')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: what are `x.shape` and `lda.transformed.shape` values?

Comment: x.shape: (8782, 3). lda_transformed.shape: (8782, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case when the number of different class labels, `C`, is less than the number of observations (almost always), then linear discriminant analysis will always produce `C - 1` discriminating components. Using `n_components` from the `sklearn` API is only a means to choose possibly *fewer* components, e.g. in the case when you know what dimensionality you'd like to reduce down to. But you could never use `n_components` to get *more* components.

This is discussed in the [Wikipedia section on Multiclass LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Multiclass_LDA). The definition of the between-class scatter is given as

```
\Sigma_{b} = (1 / C) \sum_{i}^{C}( (\mu_{i} - mu)(\mu_{i} - mu)^{T}
```

which is the empirical covariance matrix among the population of class means. [By definition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/180366/8927), such a covariance matrix has rank at most `C - 1`.

> ... the variability between features will be contained in the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to the C − 1 largest eigenvalues ...

So because LDA uses a decomposition of the *class mean* covariance matrix, it means the dimensionality reduction it can provide is based on the number of class labels, and not on the sample size nor the feature dimensionality.

In the example you linked, it doesn't matter how many *features* there are. The point is that the example uses 3 simulated cluster centers, so there are 3 class labels. This means linear discriminant analysis could produce projection of the data onto either 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional discriminating subspaces.

But in your data, you start out with only 2 class labels, a binary problem. This means the dimensionality of the linear discriminant model can be at most 1-dimensional, literally a line that forms the decision boundary between the two classes. Dimensionality reduction with LDA in this case would simply be the projection of data points onto a particular normal vector of that separating line.

If you want to specifically reduce down to two dimensions, you can try many of the other algorithms that `sklearn` provides: t-SNE, ISOMAP, PCA and kernel PCA, random projection, multi-dimensional scaling, among others. Many of these allow you to choose the dimensionality of the projected space, up to the original feature dimensionality, or sometimes you can even project into larger spaces, like with kernel PCA.

Answer (score 0):

In the [example](http://www.apnorton.com/blog/2016/12/19/Visualizing-Multidimensional-Data-in-Python/) you give, dimension reduction by LDA reduces the data from 13 features to 2 features, however in your example it reduces from 3 to 1 (even though you wanted to get 2 features), thus it is not possible to plot in 2D.

If you really want to select 2 features out of 3, you can use `feature_selection.SelectKBest` to choose 2 best features and there won't be any problems plotting in 2D.

For more information, please read this fantastic answer for PCA:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, but I tried it with a much bigger data set (200 features) and I still got the same result, hence why I wanted to ask.

Comment: @DanielSlätt Please see my answer to this question. The number of *features* you choose does not have an effect on what the dimensionality will be for linear discriminant analysis, rather it is the number of *class labels*. Because you have 2 class labels, LDA will always produce 1 discriminant component, by definition.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's because of sklearn implementation that won't allowed you to do so if you only have 2 class. The problem has been stated in here, [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1967](http://LDA%20transform%20gives%20wrong%20dimensions).

Comment: The sklearn issue link (which is currently broken), points to an issue that restates the [answer I gave above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49983865/567620), and relates to a bug that sklearn had with reporting 2 output dimensions instead of 1 in the case of a 2-D input problem. It is not related to the OP's overall question, which is instead a confusion about what possible dimensionality reduction LDA can provide.